# vagrant box tests in gitlab-ci

Tags: ansible, gitlab, github, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a vagrant box, provisioned with Ansible that needs testing on github pull requests. Is it possible to setup CI test suite for the mirror in gitlab-ci without extra expenses on droplets? Or maybe this is something that could be possible with upcoming `automation` on github? Big fan of `travis` but looks like they not going to support virtualbox deployment in their containers anytime [soon](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6060#issuecomment-221395944).

Answer (score 2):

You can do via docker, since it's a test.
Here is an example repository, both docker and vagrant.
https://github.com/jonashackt/gitlab-ci-stack
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/05/gitlab-ci-pipeline/

Comment: Thank you, saw this post before. Good approach, but I was looking to spin tests on gitlab free servers, need to check if I could include these runners in that workflow.